# redo button has never worked in android studios?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-ide

i have found  that android studios has never contained any way of 'redoing' a text edit (the opposite of ctrl+z)?
the option exists in the menu/ toolbar but is greyed out. it always has been and it has never functioned.
to test, i have created a clean, empty project, typed in the java class, moved the cursor to elsewhere in the class (incase back to default for some reason prevents it working), typed again.
i then have tested both ctrl+z and manually clicking the undo button, but i am simply NOT ABLE to use the 'redo' option at all. not once since i have been using this IDE.

can ANYONE please explain this behavious and how to get this functionality back? as im finding i often undo one step too many and forget what ive just destroyed.
thanks

Comment: I'm on 3.5.3 and it works fine. I don't really use it but I think it was working fine for me on previous versions as well. Sorry I can't help you!

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap
On the right side of the screen, search for "redo" and right-click on the Redo option.
Add a keyboard shortcut (I use ctrl+Y which is pretty standard across applications).
[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, ive already found that ctrl+shift+z works (i use ctrl+y for line delete) but still no idea why the GUI redo refuses to work. ah well, the mystery continues. i appriciate your help either way. edit: marking this as answer as i have a work around and this answer may help somone else